# Replace character between numbers

Tags: mysql, sql, phpbb3

I converted phpbb2 forum to phpbb3.
But I have problem with phpbb2 posts links which remained in MySQL database.

phpbb2 posts links are eg.

```
/viewtopic&#46;php?p=106352#106352
```

and phpbb3 are:

```
/viewtopic&#46;php?p=106352#p106352
```

(there is letter p after #)

Current links from phpbb2 are not working, after convert, 
so I need help replacing # between posts id (numbers) in MySQL DB.

I got a lot of links like:

```
/viewtopic&#46;php?p=106352#106352
```

and I need to replace # with p ( add p at the end)
like:

```
/viewtopic&#46;php?p=106352#p106352
```

I don't know much MySQL, so I stuck.

Please help

Comment: Should we assume these values are in your database? What have you tried?

Comment: In my opinion this question is an XY problem: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 1):

```
select replace('/viewtopic.php?p=106352#106352','#','#p')

update myTable
set myColumn = replace(myColumn, '#', '#p')
where someColumn = someThing
```

Comment: I know, about that, but i have almost 1000 links to change, with different numbers :(

Comment: Is your data in a table?  If so, use the `update myTable` statement above - replacing table and column names as appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

One possible approach:

```
UPDATE phpbb_posts
   SET post_text = REPLACE(post_text, '#', '#p')
 WHERE post_text REGEXP '^[^#]*p=[0-9]+#[0-9]+$'
```

`WHERE` clause is specified to prevent updating links that do not follow the format.

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/95ae7/1).

Comment: I have this links in column, where i can add that to that query ? I have table phpbb_posts and links are in column post_text

Comment: Updated the answer, but you'd really better go through even some basic SQL tutorial.

Comment: I'm getting that none records were replaced

Comment: Then please include the exact record (as it is stored in DB) to the question. with `SELECT post_text FROM phpbb_posts WHERE post_text LIKE '%#%' LIMIT 10` or something similar. My guess is that you have whitespace at the end of the link; in that case it's enough to adjust the regex accordingly (`...#[0-9]+ *$`)

Comment: When i run this query, i get results with BLOB. After click, i get: MySQL returned an empty result (zero line). I search that string, and i editted post_text to get that link. [url=http&#58;//domain&#46;com/viewtopic&#46;php?p=272#272:3eujk5cy]quinoa[/url:3eujk5cy] . /viewtopic&#46;php? and php?p=272#272 are in different lines.